# How to make a CNN model that tells it can't decide which class this image belongs to?

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, conv-neural-network

I trained a CNN model that takes an image as input and maps this image to one of 3 classes. But I know there are more than 3 classes that this image can belong to. But my model is only trained on these 3 classes. So, what I want to do is to make a model that can tell that this image doesn't belong to one of those classes (the model doesn't know what class this image belongs to) instead of giving a probability to each class like [10, 10, 80] for example. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can't do it. That's how deep learning models work. You train a model with x classes but optionally you can add an extra class that can be something probably that happens. i.g you train a model to detect lemons in a conveyor belt.. then you say I will train my model with images of lemons in the coveyor belt.. now what if there is not lemons? your model will told you that it's a lemon.. then what should do is train also the model with images of the conveyor belt without lemons. Anyways the model will tell you the highest probability.

Answer (score 0):

Machine learning or deep learning models are made for computers to learn from some data. It is the humans are responsible for teaching the data to them. If humans don't specify a particular class, there is no chance for a machine learning model to predict something beyond. Because the computer doesn't know anything about it. This is the basics of machine learning actually. It is not magic; it is a tool to learn patterns from something complicated.

PS: Try something within artificial general intelligence. It directly will not help you in any sort regarding the question but would help you learn about the deeper aspects of how humans and machines think.